# VSTO Outlook Add-In won't load while Outlook is running

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in

We created a simple Outlook VSTO Add-In using a ClickOnce installer. If Outlook is already running (which is common) when the installer is run, the Add-In doesn't load. It only loads after restarting Outlook.

Is there anyway to force the Add-In to load directly after ClickOnce installation (even if Outlook is already running)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to restart Outlook to get the add-in loaded. See [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hmm. Shoot. So create a small executable that restarts outlook and have ClickOnce install the add-in then run the executable?

Comment: As a possible solution, yes.